# Most efficient way to insert a post outside WordPress?

Tags: posts, xml-rpc

I need to insert a post via `PHP` outside the Wordpress environment (but on the same server) and I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

I was thinking about 2 solutions:

1) Using XML-RPC, as explained [here](http://www.hurricanesoftwares.com/wordpress-xmlrpc-posting-content-from-outside-wordpress-admin-panel/)

2) Load the WordPress core requiring `wp-load.php` and then using `wp_insert_post()`

Wich one uses less resources? I just need to insert a new post into the database and I don't need any support for plugins, theming, etc. There is a more *hackish* way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer has already been given, so don't take this as a rep-steal, but for those who don't know how to do this, I have a [blog article](http://ericholmes.ca/using-wordpress-core-externally/) explaining how.

Comment: what is the PHP code you're running? Custom PHP files? A plugin or themes AJAX handler? A drupal install? A symfony/zend/laravel applicaiton?

Comment: @TomJNowell a custom PHP application that programmately insert new posts into WordPress.

Comment: what framework does it use?

Comment: @TomJNowell no PHP frameworks involved at all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If you're on a remote server**, XMLRPC would be best, but requires login details

**If you're in a PHP script on the same server**, `wp-load.php` would be best ( XMLRPC will involve a request of sorts )

**If you're in a bash or CLI script**, WP CLI would be best, e.g.:

```
wp post create --post_type=page --post_status=publish --post_title='A future post' --post-status=future --post_date='2020-12-01 07:00:00'
```

[More on WP CLIs create post command](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/create/)

**If you're crazy**, a raw SQL insert, fast, cheap, doesnt fire off all the hooks and API calls needed, most incompatible option with plugins, caches, etc

**If you're even crazier**, you could write out a WXR file, then run the WordPress Importer

**If you're patient**, provide it as an RSS and have WordPress use an aggregation plugin to pull it in

## If you're Sane

Then no external script will be there to begin with, and you will have built a plugin, used the WP AJAX API, not created a dedicated file for a form handler etc.

***Unless*** you're in some Symfony or Zend setup, your question indicates you're doing something horribly wrong.

If you **are** in such a situation though, there are libraries for that, libraries  such as:

https://github.com/kayue/KayueWordpressBundle

Amongst others.

## But For You achairapart

I would say that `wp-load.php` is probably the safest and most compatible way that doesn't require expensive http requests. It's also how most of the libraries will implement it, it's also how I would do it.

But keep in mind, inserting/creating a post in WordPress is an inherently expensive thing to do. You can reduce the load but it will never be a fast and quick operation unless you're running a site that has no plugins or posts and contains only the hello world sample post and page.

Comment: +1 for recap all the options available. However, I think I'm enough sane to looking for a way to minimize all the resources I can even if I'm not using any PHP framework.

Comment: I would still look into symfony bundles, and other libraries, you don't have to buy into the framework to use the nice parts

Comment: @achairapart note my edits

Answer (score 3):

> Which one uses less resources?

Neither, really.

> I don't need any support for plugins, theming, etc.

I think you've answered your own question. Go for the latter technique (`wp-load.php`).

Comment: One involves a http request and login details, the other doesn't, they're not equivalant

Answer (score 2):

> There is a more hackish way to do this?

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hackish) *hackish* means:

> poorly designed workarounds

You could do it directly via SQL or even generate some `.sql` file and import it directly to your database ;-)

This path will probably be unflexible and even muddy, but *hackish* yes ;-)

But in general I would go with number `2`).

Answer (score 0):

As you are on the same server, why not do a custom sql quary, I think it will use less server resource than loading core file using wp-load.php

Comment: Yes, this is the _crazy option_ one (quoting @TomJNowell), but it actually will miss very important things like sanitizing inputs, future-proof compatibility, etc.

Comment: My bad, I did not think this way.